# How to create the set of all possible sets formed by selecting 0 or 1 elements from n lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

As an example, say I have the following six lists:

```
[2], [2,3], [4], [1,2], [2], [1,4]
```

I want to make a new list that has either 0 or 1 elements from each of these lists. One such list could be `[2,2,4,1,2,1]` which is made by selecting the first element from each list. Another such list could be `[2,3,2,2,4]` which is made by selecting the last element from each list. Another could be `[2,4,1,2]` which has no elements from the first and last lists. How can I form a list of lists (in python) that has all possible lists made from selecting either 0 or 1 elements from these six lists? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the *product* of all the lists. To include the case where you select zero elements from any given list, you can add `None` to all the lists, and then remove `None` elements before you yield a selection.

This assumes you don't have any `None`s in the original lists. If you do, you can replace the `None`s in this logic with some dummy value that your lists won't contain.

```
import itertools

def optional_product(*iterables, dummy=None):
    iterables = [itertools.chain(itbl, [dummy]) for itbl in iterables]

    for selection in itertools.product(*iterables):
        sel = [s for s in selection if s != dummy]
        yield sel
```

Note: To support iterables other than lists, I use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to "append" a `None` to each input iterable.

To run this:

```
for sel in optional_product([2], [2,3], [4], [1,2], [2], [1,4]):
    print(sel)
```

which prints:

```
[2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 4, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 2]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 2]
[2, 2, 4, 1]
[2, 2, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 4]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 1, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 4, 1, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 4]
[2, 4]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 1]
[2, 4]
[2]
[2, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 2]
[2, 4, 1, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2]
[2, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 4]
[2, 4]
[2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 4]
[2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 1]
[2, 4]
[2]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 1, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 4]
[3, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 2, 2, 4]
[3, 4, 2, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 2, 4]
[3, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1]
[3, 4, 2, 4]
[3, 4, 2]
[3, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 1, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 4]
[3, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 4]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 4]
[3, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 4]
[3, 2]
[3, 1]
[3, 4]
[3]
[4, 1, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 2, 4]
[4, 1, 2]
[4, 1, 1]
[4, 1, 4]
[4, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 2, 4]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 4]
[4, 2]
[4, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 4]
[4, 2]
[4, 1]
[4, 4]
[4]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2]
[1, 1]
[1, 4]
[1]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 4]
[2, 2]
[2, 1]
[2, 4]
[2]
[2, 1]
[2, 4]
[2]
[1]
[4]
[]
```

The last value yielded is the case where zero elements are selected from *all* lists. If you don't want this, you can simply `yield sel` only when `sel` is non-empty.

To obtain a list of lists containing all selections, just do `list(optional_product(...))`